# Migrating PowerBuilder Application Build Process to TeamCity

Tags: migration, teamcity, cruisecontrol.net, powerbuilder, orca

I currently have a PowerBuilder application that I recently migrated to PowerBuilder 2017 from PowerBuilder 12.5.  I was using CruiseControl.net with Orca scripts to build my PowerBuilder projects.  However the machine I was using to build also had PowerBuilder installed on it.  I would like to migrate this PowerBuilder project to TeamCity.  Would I need to install PowerBuilder on my TeamCity server to accomplish this or is it possible to do this without that similar to how you can build a Visual Studio project with just the Visual Studio build tools?  We have a finite number of PowerBuilder developer licenses and would prefer to not have to use them just for build machines.

Comment: it's not a question to teamcity. teamcity is just a runner of your orca-script. ihmo, question to powerbuilder or orca licensing. for sure to build PB application you need powerbuilder on teamcity agent installed. maybe you can find third-party compiling tools to avoid licensing... better to ask SAP?...

Comment: With PB2017 you need to go to Appeon, not SAP.  This question would be better suited for the community portal on Appeon's site.